# How to Make Exact Selection Multiple Times

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, selections

I have just started to learn photoshop (including php, css and html5 to become a designer). I am using videos tutorials to learn. However one issue that i've been facing and i have searched a lot for solution without success.

It is making exact sized selection multiple times. Using elliptical tool second time always differs by 1 or 2 pixels.

because i am new, so i may not be able to express (using professional terminology) what exactly i want to do. So here is the photo. Round selection is made using elliptical marquee tool.

**now i want to make exact size selection on another layer.**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select once... With the selection active...

Choose `Select > Save Selection` - Leave everything as it is and add a name you'll recognize.

When you need it again, choose `Select > Load Selection` and choose the saved selection you want from the `Channel` dropdown.

Comment: already tried that too. but that did not solved my issue. is there anyway way i can move the selection (i can place anywhere i want on layer) after loading? @Scott

Comment: @anniestewart absolutely, just use the Marquee tool and you can click-drag a selection anywhere. You can even use `Edit > Transform Selection` to transform it (without altering underlying pixels)

Comment: It sounds as though you may benefit a great deal by reviewing this: https://helpx.adobe.com/in/photoshop/how-to/selection-tools-basics.html Most of this is covered as basic functionality and the Adobe Help will walk you through the general possibilities.